# JNI : Is it possible to avoid create a lot of Java object in JNI?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I want to improve performance of my code here:

```
    jclass segWordClazz = env->FindClass("xxx/yyy/SegWord");
    jmethodID initMethodId = env->GetMethodID(segWordClazz, "<init>", "(Ljava/lang/String;II)V");

    jsize size = (jsize) words.size();
    jobjectArray arr = env->NewObjectArray(size, segWordClazz, NULL);
    jint i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        jstring word = env->NewStringUTF(words[i].word.c_str());
        jobject obj = env->NewObject(segWordClazz, initMethodId, word,
                                     (jint) words[i].unicode_offset,
                                     (jint) words[i].unicode_offset + words[i].unicode_length);

        env->SetObjectArrayElement(arr, i, obj);
        env->DeleteLocalRef(obj);
        env->DeleteLocalRef(word);
    }
```

What I am trying to do is, split a text into words, but if the text is too long, it may generate too many words that cause a lot of `NewObject` allocation (1 or 2 million maybe more).

I was wondering if it possible to improve the performance here? This piece of code takes too much time to execute.

Comment: You mean, the length of your **arr** is over a million, and it takes too long to populate it? And you suspect **NewObject** is the step that should be optimized? Does **SegWord** constructor do something special? You should first profile your code to find the bottleneck(s).

Comment: How certain are you that object creation in JNI is your performance bottleneck?  If you're parsing that much text, your bottleneck could be I/O or the parsing.  Never guess where you need to optimize - you're quite likely to be wrong.  Benchmark and measure performance to *find* your bottleneck(s).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is sequentially iterating and processing some input.

I do not see how you could reduce the object footprint (as I do not know your requirements - you don't explain why you are doing things exactly this way).

But regarding the overall runtime: consider "slicing" your input data into several "partitions - that would enable you to run things in parallel. That would even increase memory consumption, but should allow for faster processing.

Comment: You are right, memory reducing seems not possible here, just removed it.

Comment: Having several "distinct" questions within one question is discouraged here anyway :-)